# Start microsoft edge with inprivate mode from shortcut on windows 10 build 1809

Tags: microsoft-edge

I used to have a shortcut on my desktop that started a webbased tool in edge in the inprivate mode. I had to do this because I need to single sign on with an other user than my domain user. Only the inprivate mode in edge does this without problem (Chrome seems to switch back to my regular account).

I can start edge, open an inprivate browser manually. But I would be nice to have my shortcut working again.

The shortcut looks like this:

```
%windir%\System32\cmd.exe "/c start shell:AppsFolder\Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe!MicrosoftEdge -private https://www.somedomain.com"
```

This worked until I updated windows to build 1809. I cannot seem to find another sollution.

Comment: This should go to superuser

Comment: I made a test on my side and I am able to produce the issue on my side with Win 10 1809 build. I will try to submit the feedback regarding this issue to the website for MS Edge issues. Thanks for your understanding.